# applicability of java bean concepts

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm sometimes a little bit confused about concepts in Java EE application development.

Let's assume that I have structured data or objects that concern multiple clients simultaneously. For instance, I might have an application which makes heavy use of dynamic data like transient coordinates of cars that should be tracked (no need to persist them), and above that I might want to offer services to clients. I think that neither session beans nor entity beans are appropriate to represent this sort of data, or?  Session beans are in general not suitable for representing multiple instances of an object in the context of one client, am I right?

So does an typical Java EE application not only consist of session beans and entity beans, but also of Pojos? *How do I represent transient objects, that are not specific to one client?* Please excuse my noobish questions, I just need a general notion about that...

Comment: "dynamic data like cordinates of cars" is not sufficiently precise to answer. WOuldn't you like to keep these persistent? What if you need several servers to handle the load?

Comment: You're right, this was indeed a bit inconclusive. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a case, you would indeed use POJOs stored in some in-memory collection to represent your transient data.

Session beans are either stateless (so can't contain shared data) or stateful (which mean they contain conversational data for one client only). Entities are persistent.